# Why do I get an unhandled promise error when i dont have a promise set?

Tags: javascript, sql, reactjs, http, axios

I ran into an issue with an axios post request

```
const addOrder = (newOrder) => {
axios
  .post("http://localhost:83/api/addorder", {
    newRow: newOrder,
    newRecID: orders[0].RecID + 1,
  })
  .then((response) => {
    console.log(response);
    getOrders();
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.log("Err", err);
  });
```

In my API the request handler is this:

```
app.post("/api/addorder", function (req, res) {
  const newData = req.body.newOrder;
  let newRecID = req.body.newRecID; 

  sql.connect(config, function (err) {
  if (err) {
      console.log(err);
      return;
    }
    var request = new sql.Request();

request.query(
  `INSERT INTO dbo.Einkauf_Web_Bestellungen_DEV (RecID) VALUES (${newRecID})`,

  function (err, result) {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
  }
);


 });
  });
```

The SQL Query is executed and succesfully inserts the given value. But my react application crashes and spits out following error:

[Screenshot of the application console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H3ZdB.png)

Comment: Side note; your query seems to be vulnerable to [SQL Injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).

Comment: @Ivar thanks for the input, but the application is only used in our intranet. Would appriciate your help with the promise issue.

Comment: Also on intranet I wouldn't leave vulnerabilities in my application. (Especially if they are easy to fix like here.) I don't have any experience with Axios or React, so I'm not sure how much I can help you here. But the error says it is thrown at `react-dom.development.js` on line 11340 (you should be able to click that in your console). What code does that exactly point to?

Comment: Try, sending a response in the API handler. `function (err, result) {
 if (err) {
  console.log(err);
  } else {
   res.send("ok");
  }`

Comment: @AjitKumar did not work :/

Comment: @Ivar that code is created with create-react-app, its not written by me